# Docker-compose doesn't create postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker Desktop 4.23.0, I also have a little webapp written in Java 17 with Spring Boot 3.1.3.

I have the issues below:

If I create a `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_DB=test-docker
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=230483
ENV POSTGRES_USER=giacomo

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["postgres"]
```

and build the image and create and run the container with the follow command:

```bash
docker run -d --name [container-name] -p 5433:5432 [image-name]
```

I changed the port because I have PostgreSQL 12 engine on my machine and I have read that can cause conflict

I can connect with DBeaver at the DB just created with the follow parameters:

```
host: host.docker.internal
port: 5433
user: giacomo
db: test-docker
password: 230483
```

Now I would like to put the db, the REST-API (back-end) and the front-end - written in Angular - all inside Docker to test the whole project. I have the follow `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pgsql-test-compose
    volumes:
      - new-pgsql-container-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: attilio
      POSTGRES_DB: test-docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 230483
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  api:
     build:
       context: C:/workspace2022-09/docker/docker
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     container_name: app-test-compose
     image: app-compose
     depends_on:
       - db
     environment:
       DB_HOST: db
     volumes:
       - /tmp
     ports:
       - 8080:8080
  app:
     build:
       context: C:/workspace2022-09/docker/docker-fe/dockerfe
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     container_name: gui-test-compose
     image: gui-compose
     depends_on:
       - api
     ports:
       - 4200:80
  
volumes:
  new-pgsql-container-data:
    name: new-pgsql-container-data
```

I run the `docker-compose.yml` with the follow command:

```bash
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -p test-container up --build --remove-orphans -d
```

The Angular app is up and working, the back-end is up and even the SwaggerUI works, but no db (test-docker) is created.

If I try to connect with DBeaver (or PGAdmin), the connection is refused. I really don't understand why with Dockerfile the DB is created and with `docker-compose.yml` not!

What's wrong?

Comment: If I `docker compose up db` using your `compose.yaml` without any changes, it works just fine: postgres creates a `test-docker` database, and I can authenticate as the "attilio" user.

Comment: ...but you should probably drop the `version: "1"` from your compose file; it is [not required](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/04-version-and-name.md) and the most reason version is >= 3.

Comment: Postgres only creates a database if the data directory is empty. Try deleting your volume. Then, when you bring the system up, it should create the database.

Comment: Thanks @HansKilian your solution worked! Sorry for the question I'm new to Docker and I forget volume is persistent and will not overwritten.